# Parsing JSON in SQL Server 2017 (Clearbit API call)

Tags: json, api, parsing, sql-server-2017

I'm pulling some data into a database on my local server with API calls via Clearbit provider. Everything was OK regarding parsing the data with SQL Server 2017 until I hit a bump.

I will go straight on the example for easier understanding.

*This is the example of an API call output in JSON*

```
{
  "id": "384dfe0d-5bba-445e-a390-2d946dc84a12",
  "name": "Honeywell",
  "legalName": "Honeywell International Inc",
  "domain": "honeywell.com",
  "domainAliases": [
    "honeywell.at",
    "honeywell.it",
    "evohome.info",
    "wifithermostat.com",
    "emsaviation.com",
    "mytotalconnect.com",
    "honeywell.nl",
    "honeywell.co.za",
    "honeywell.com.au",
    "honeywell.ca",
    "alliedsignal.com",
    "emsdss.com",
    "primusepic.com",
    "alarmnet-me.com",
    "lebow.com",
    "honeywell.ie",
    "honeywell.jp",
    "honeywell.com.br",
    "trendcontrol.co.uk",
    "honeywellforjaguar.co.uk",
    "aviaso.com",
    "skyforce.co.uk",
    "newenglandinstruments.com",
    "honeywell.fi",
    "alarmnet.com",
    "skyconnect.com",
    "skyforceuk.com",
    "securitex.com",
    "missionready.com",
    "honeywellaerospace.com",
    "formation.com",
    "aclon.com",
    "electrocorp.com",
    "ultrak.com",
    "satcom1.com",
    "hsmpats.com",
    "myaerospace.com",
    "emsglobaltracking.com",
    "fascocontrols.com",
    "honeywellnow.com",
    "bendixbrakes.com",
    "elmwoodsensors.com",
    "ovationselect.com",
    "honeywellbusinessaviation.com",
    "iflyaspire.com",
    "btrinc.com",
    "honeywellspecialtymaterials.com",
    "magneticsensors.com",
    "activeye.com",
    "egarrett.com",
    "novar-eds.com",
    "aviaso.co.uk",
    "chadwick-helmuth.com",
    "datainstruments.com",
    "lebowproducts.com",
    "honeywell-produktkatalog.de",
    "honeywellforjaguar.com",
    "hobbs-corp.com",
    "emsgt.com",
    "honeywellaes.com",
    "honeywellbuildingsolutions.com",
    "satcom1.aero",
    "honeywell-building-solutions.de",
    "lifesafetydistribution.com",
    "godirect.com",
    "garrettbulletin.com",
    "yourhomeexpert.com",
    "aerospacetrading.com",
    "sensorsystems.com",
    "wifithermostat.info",
    "honeywell-fachseminare.de",
    "hobbscorporation.com",
    "kcl.hu",
    "honeywell.sk",
    "esser.info",
    "inertialsensor.com",
    "sensotec.com",
    "notifier.com",
    "honeywellgreer.com",
    "smartact.de",
    "honeywellfire.com",
    "iris-systems.com",
    "honeywell.ru",
    "lxei.com",
    "thermalswitch.com",
    "hightempsolutions.com",
    "aubetech.com",
    "honeywell-haustechnik.de",
    "careersathoneywell.com",
    "garrettbyhoneywell.com",
    "honeywell.in",
    "honeywell.cn",
    "honeywell.com.mx",
    "kcp.com",
    "satamatics.com",
    "myflite.com"
  ],
  "site": {
    "title": "Honeywell",
    "h1": null,
    "metaDescription": " We are blending products with software solutions to link people and businesses to the information they need to be more efficient, safer and connected. ",
    "metaAuthor": null,
    "phoneNumbers": [
      "+1 877-271-8620",
      "+1 800-633-3991",
      "+1 877-841-2840",
      "+1 480-353-3020",
      "+1 973-455-3388",
      "+1 973-204-9621",
      "+32 2 728 20 45",
      "+32 476 20 90 19",
      "+44 7794 007289",
      "+86 21 2219 6509"
    ],
    "emailAddresses": [
      "domains@honeywell.com",
      "HoneywellPrivacy@honeywell.com",
      "rob.ferris@honeywell.com",
      "ilse.schouteden@honeywell.com",
      "chris.martin2@honeywell.com",
      "Anahi.Espinosa@honeywell.com",
      "lydia.lu@honeywell.com",
      "madhavi.jha@Honeywell.com",
      "Steven.Brecken@Honeywell.com",
      "Steve.Brecken@Honeywell.com",
      "Eugene.Tan@Honeywell.com"
    ]
  },
  "category": {
    "sector": "Consumer Discretionary",
    "industryGroup": "Automobiles & Components",
    "industry": "Automotive",
    "subIndustry": "Automotive",
    "sicCode": "3714",
    "naicsCode": null
  },
  "tags": [
    "Automotive",
    "Enterprise",
    "B2B",
    "Electrical"
  ],
  "description": " We are blending products with software solutions to link people and businesses to the information they need to be more efficient, safer and connected. ",
  "foundedYear": 1936,
  "location": "115 Tabor Rd, Morris Plains, NJ 07950, USA",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "utcOffset": -4,
  "geo": {
    "streetNumber": "115",
    "streetName": "Tabor Road",
    "subPremise": null,
    "city": "Morris Plains",
    "postalCode": "07950",
    "state": "New Jersey",
    "stateCode": "NJ",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "lat": 40.8358456,
    "lng": -74.4771042
  },
  "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/honeywell.com",
  "facebook": {
    "handle": "293855263965203",
    "likes": null
  },
  "linkedin": {
    "handle": "company/honeywell"
  },
  "twitter": {
    "handle": "HoneywellNow",
    "id": "257492733",
    "bio": "Please visit us over at @Honeywell.",
    "followers": 2322,
    "following": 1,
    "location": "Morris Plains, NJ",
    "site": "https:",
    "avatar": 
  },
  "crunchbase": {
    "handle": "organization/honeywell"
  },
  "emailProvider": false,
  "type": "public",
  "ticker": "HON",
  "phone": "+1 973-455-2000",
  "metrics": {
    "alexaUsRank": 6045,
    "alexaGlobalRank": 18053,
    "googleRank": null,
    "employees": 51779,
    "employeesRange": "1000+",
    "marketCap": 102920000000,
    "raised": null,
    "annualRevenue": 39302000000,
    "fiscalYearEnd": 12
  },
  "indexedAt": "2017-07-11T23:00:41.115Z",
  "tech": [
    "crazy_egg",
    "google_analytics",
    "google_tag_manager",
    "asp_net",
    "mouseflow",
    "marketo",
    "go_squared",
    "microsoft_exchange_online",
    "outlook",
    "recaptcha"
  ],
  "parent": {
    "domain": null
  },
  "similarDomains": [
    "abb-livingspace.com",
    "alerton.com",
    "gereports.com",
    "honeywellprocess.com",
    "honeywelluk.com",
    "johnsoncontrols.com",
    "jpinstruments.com",
    "lenel.com",
    "maxitrol.com",
    "nucalgon.com",
    "schneider-electric.us",
    "siemens.com"
  ]
}
```

If you look at the example up here you will see `"domainAliases": [...]`
and that is the part of the JSON I still need to parse.

*This is the parse query for SQL that I already have:*

```
SELECT * 
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData,'$.name') AS CompanyName
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData,'$.category.sector') AS CategorySector
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.category.industryGroup') AS CategoryIndustryGroup
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.category.industry') AS CategoryIndustry
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.category.subIndustry') AS CategorySubIndustry
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.category.sicCode') AS CategorySicCode
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.category.naicsCode') AS CategoryNaicsCode
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.metrics.employees') AS EmployeesNumber
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.metrics.employeesRange') AS EmployeesRange
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.metrics.marketCap') AS MarketCap
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.metrics.annualRevenue') AS AnnualRevenue
     , JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.similarDomains') AS SimilarDomains
FROM Domains;
```

I want this data ("domainAliases") to be stored in other table as the data in the upper query (I know that the parse query I already have is only a SELECT query but I also have an UPDATE version of the query).

*Here is an example picture of how the finished product in a **new table**, same database should look. The left column is called `Company Name`, the 2nd column is called `Domain Aliases`:*

[image: The left column is called Company Name, the 2nd column is called Domain Aliases.]

Now **WHERE** is the **JSON** data stored? I have it stored in a Column called `JSONData`, tablename: `Domains` and all this is in a database called `Domainbank`. `JSONData` datatype is `nvarchar(max)`.

I need the data to be grouped by the name of the company and next to the company name there should be aliases domain just like the picture example shows. Now keep in mind that I will run this query for 10k+ `JSONData`s and the new table that is going to be created will be super huge but as long as it is all grouped by the company name with all the alias domains it should be good. Some of the `JSONData`s did not return the API call in the correct format because they either didn't find the data or something else went wrong, so If the query doesnt find anyting under the `"domainAliases": [...]` or if it doesn't even find the `"domainAliases": [...]` then I don't need the company to appear on the new table.

So short recap: let's make a new table (Let's call it `AliasDomains`), find the data under `"domainAliases": [...]` also pull the company name out `JSON_VALUE(JSONData,'$.name') AS CompanyName`, Store the data in the new table as the picture example higher in the post and then group by `CompanyName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from your post I am not completely clear on what your question is, but I assume it is how to write some SQL statement to accomplish the above?

First of all, I'd say you should not care of the `GROUP BY` in the insert, do `GROUP BY` when retrieving data out of the table.

Having said that you can quite easily accomplish what you want with a `SELECT` from the `Domains` table together with a `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` statement, like so:

```
INSERT INTO AliasDomains(CompanyName, DomainAliases)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(JSONData, '$.name'), value 
FROM Domains
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (JSONData, '$.domainAliases')
```

**EDIT:** Should probably add that `value` in the above statement is returned from `OPENJSON`, e.g. it references the values of the (in this case `domainAliases`) path you want.

Hope this helps?!

Niels